# How can I disable tap-to-click on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, tap-to-click

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 and I'm trying to find out how to disable "tap-to-click".

This worked for me on previous Ubuntu releases:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
```

... but on 17.10, I get this error:

```
(process:6941): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

I also check system dialog, and Ubuntu Tweak, but there is no option to disable tap-to-click in the graphical interface.

How can I disable tap-to-click in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Have you tried using `dconf-editor` to make this change?  It is a GUI interface to gsettings, and you can navigate through the tree the to the same specific setting that you mention above.

Comment: When i open "dconf-editor" from my user account i can navigate to tap-to-click,  and it's already  disabled. https://i.imgur.com/XSfTncO.png

Comment: Is you computer doing a tap-to-click action even though it is disabled?

Comment: Yes, when  i'm writing and my palm barley touch "touch pad"  it's registering  clicking. I'm trying to get rid of this.

Comment: I have a lazy wrist as well - I can commiserate with you.  I assume that `disable-while-typing` is on for your touchpad (although this seems to time out quickly).  If you do not have a log of settings modified in dconf, you could `mv ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/dconf.bak` and then try again to disable the click to tap

Comment: I deleted /.config/dconf , after reboot  still clicking on touch. Opened dconf-editor  and find "tap-to-click" enabled, i set to false, reboot,  still  tap to click working. When open dconf-editor  it's disabled,  i disable also "double finger scrolling" and it still working,   I suspect it might be something about "wayland" , maybe it's change it for old x.org and it's not applying that changes?

Comment: I checked, and i'm on x11.  I found out when i use "sign in to unity" it working perfect (being disabled just like i set)  https://imgur.com/a/DkwXQ     (on ubuntu xorg) changes not being apply.

Comment: If you `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` what do you get now?

Comment: x11 is being displayed on both

Answer (score 1):

Right, so to disable this behaviour I tend to run:

```
#Disable tap to click
synclient MaxTapTime=0 
#Disable drag
synclient TapAndDragGesture=0
#enable palm detection
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

To make it stick we can add a desktop file to ~/.config/autostart
Such as "touchpad.desktop":

```
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Touchpadset
Icon=Icon
Exec="synclient MaxTapTime=0 && synclient TapAndDragGesture=0 && synclient PalmDetect=1" 
Comment=Set touchpad options 
Categories=Login
Terminal=false
```

This should keep working until ubuntu switches to libinput.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. For a workaround, I use two scripts to turn the touchpad on and off:

```
# from ~/bin/s0
synclient touchpadoff=0
```

and

```
# from ~/bin/s1
synclient touchpadoff=1
```

When I'm annoyed by the cursor jumping around from hitting my palm, I `Ctrl+Alt+T`, `s1`, `<Enter>`, `Ctrl+D`. When I need the cursor again, I run `s0` insted.

I'm sincerely hoping for a proper fix as well! I had better palm detection *and* the ability to disable tap-to-click on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.